# How to Guarantee that Construction Phase Initializes All Entities' Planning Variables?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Occasionally, if I have my Construction Phase's "Seconds Spent" and "Unimproved Seconds Spent" termination settings set for too short an amount of time, I end up with a few Planning Entities that do not have all of their Planning Variables initialized. This results in my Search Phase throwing exceptions regarding uninitialized Planning Variables (`Local Search phase (1) needs to start from an initialized solution`...).

This seems to (partially) defeat the purpose of the Construction Phase. I feel like I am missing a caveat somewhere? Maybe I am over-configuring my Construction Phase?

Here is my Construction Phase's configuration code. I am using Java to configure my Solver rather than XML.

```
TerminationConfig terminationConfig = new TerminationConfig();
ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig phaseConfig = new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig();

terminationConfig.setSecondsSpentLimit(60L);
terminationConfig.setUnimprovedSecondsSpentLimit(30L);
terminationConfig.setBestScoreLimit("0hard/0medium/0soft");

phaseConfig.setConstructionHeuristicType(ConstructionHeuristicType.FIRST_FIT);

phaseConfig.setTerminationConfig(terminationConfig);

phaseConfigs.add(phaseConfig);
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Is there a "correct" way to guarantee that all Planning Variables of all Planning Entities will be initialized by the end of the Construction Phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in terminating the CH before it's finished if you want to run the LS.
Let it finish and put a termination on the `<localSearch>` instead of the `<solver>` (the API supports this too, of course), to avoid it finishing too early.

There are many ways to make the CH go faster though, see docs.

Alternatively, combining every termination with an `AND` of a `<bestScoreFeasible>true</>` termination (= it can only terminate if a feasible solution is found) can also do what you want I believe, even as a global `<solver>` termination.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I see now where the docs say "Construction heuristics terminate automatically, so there’s usually no need to configure a Termination on the construction heuristic phase specifically." Also, for anyone else interested, the "Scaling Construction Heuristics" section of the docs discusses ways to optimize the Construction Phase.